# ASP.NET MVC 2 is comparable to what PHP MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been doing a lot with ASP.NET MVC 2 at work and I'd like to utilize my new skills at home... but I have Apache servers, not IIS.

What PHP MVC solutions are the same or at least comparable to ASP.NET MVC 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

;-) Here's a list another developer has found: http://www.mustap.com/phpzone_post_73_top-10-php-mvc-frameworks.

The #1 solution he recommends is [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use mono? I believe you can directly use your asp.net mvc skills and deploy to your apache servers.

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of PHP MVCs to look at:

- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
- [Expression Engine](http://expressionengine.com/)
- [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/)
- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)

Kohana is the only one I've done work with and I found it fairly easy to get started.  It's open source and specifically created to support PHP 5.2+ so it has a clean, object-oriented codebase.